# Serial interfaces and sysfs. How to get a unique identifier for each serial port

Tags: usb, udev, tty

I want to enumerate the serial ports on a Linux system and get unique and stable (across reboots) identifiers for them. Stable in the sense that when I plug and unplug serial USB devices (same USB port) I want to get the same identifier. Also when I reboot the machine the same serial port should get the same identifier. This should be device independent, so I do not want to set-up specific udev rules for each device I plug-in. It should work in generic way.

At first I though the kernel devpath could be used for that, but that is not so easy (see below)

To list the devpaths of the serial interfaces we can use

```
realpath /sys/class/tty/*/device
```

Which for my system yields

```
/sys/devices/pnp0/00:02
/sys/devices/pnp0/00:03
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250
```

(Of course the 'serial8250' entries [may not be real](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/Serial), but that is not the matter here)

We see that there are duplicate entries, which means that the kernel devpath is not a unique identifier for the actual serial port.

So the question is how to get a unique and stable (across reboots) identifier for the serial port?

On the other hand we find under `tty/` a list of entries which seem to contain information on the actual port, including a 'line' entry

```
/sys/devices/pnp0/00:02/tty/ttyS0/line
/sys/devices/pnp0/00:03/tty/ttyS1/line
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS2/line
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS3/line
```

that contains a single number. (0 ... 4 in this case)

What is the semantics of this `/<devpath>/tty/<id>/line`? Is is just an arbitrary numbering?
The issue is that USB serial ports do not have a 'line' entry.

Also the entries under `/<devpath>/tty/` seem to be dependent on each other, so there is some global numbering involved. So I am not sure what happens if I connect multiple serial USB devices. Do the receive different names `<devpath1>/tty/ttyUSB0` and `<devpath2>/tty/ttyUSB1` depending on the order they are plugged in or they are all have a `<devpath>/tty/ttyUSB0`? The former case would be bad as then the numbering depends on the order they were plugged in (or be random in case of reboot).

Comment: Try this: ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/* I'm not sure if this will give you fixed id names for two exactly the same hardware ports. But for different types/manuf/product of serial ports it works.

Comment: Thanks, but /dev/serial does not exist on my system, so it is not something I can rely on.

Comment: Some USB devices have unique serial numbers, while other's just have `00000000` or `12345678`. With unique serial numbers you can identify your devices uniquely; that's what serial numbers are intended for. However we don't know your devices.